# What networking type do I need to use in my VirtualBox network?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have 3 virtual machines, one acting as a client machine (xubuntu), one acting as a proxy server (ubuntu server) and one acting as a web server (ubuntu server). Each Virtual Machine will need to need to access the internet, as well as the other virtual machines.

I have tried to look into the virtual networking, but am slightly confused as to which one to use. The popular opinion seemingly being, Bridged, Host-Only or Internal.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Will they also be communicating with the host?

Comment: They will not need to connect with the host, but will each need access to the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Host-only** provides a direct network connection between the guest and the host.  The guest can connect to other sites, but the other sites can't direct connect to the guest.

The **NAT** remaps the IP as if it came from the Host.

The **Bridged** mode creates a new virtual adapter with it's own unique IP.

The Bridged mode is the one you will need to choose if you want two-way communications between the guest and other computers.  This is a requirement of any computer that will be functioning as a server or provides services that will be accessed from other computers.

Either mode can access other virtual machines.  But you will require the bridged mode if for other virtual machines to access the particular guest machine directly.

### Configuring a Bridged Adapter

Configuring the host with the bridged adapter is done no different than any computer.  You have two options.

1. The GUI option, via NetworkManager
2. Editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

If you edit the `/etc/network/interfaces`  file, this configuration will take presence over the Network Manger, and would disable Network Manager for this particular interface.

In Ubuntu, all NICs are DHCP configured by default.  So unless you specify something different, the adapter will poll the DHCP server for configuration.

You can check verify the configuration with a variation of these command-lines:

```
$ hostname -I
$ ip address | egrep inet
$ ifconfig
```

If you will be connecting to the computer from outside your local network you will have to **configure your router to forward traffic** (for the particular port of the service) to that particular computer.  You could have to look at the configuration of the server configuration to see which port to forward.  By default a web server uses **port 80**.  So if the service is a web server, you would configure your router to port traffic on port 80 to the IP of that computer.  The default port of a **Mysql database server** is port **3306**.

If you want to be sure that a specific computer has the same IP address you can use one of the two methods above to manually specify the IP address of that computer (Network Manager or editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file).

Your router will also have a method of reserving a specific IP address to a specific computer.  So you can perform this default consistent IP address via the router, rather than editing the network adapter.

In other words, **configuring the bridged adapter of the guest machine** is no different than configuring the NIC of any machine.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions of video tutorials that would show me how to set this up, step-by-step?

Comment: Give me about 15 minutes to add the details to the answer.